# Spring SimpleCacheManager update strategy?

Tags: java, database, spring, caching, spring-cache

I'm adding caching to a small but frequently used database call in my application. The table it's hitting will update very infrequently, so it's a great candidate for caching. I've implemented it with org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager, and I'd like to know more about its update strategy, but I can't seem to find anything about it.

Mostly, I'd like to know if it periodically evicts the cache, and if it does, what kind of schedule does it do it on? I'm almost certain that the default caching will work, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The properties you have to know are "timeToIdleSeconds" and
>   "timeToLiveSeconds" (in ehcache caching framework) which will decide how long the cache objects are
>   valid for.  Once the cache data becomes invalid, the data will be fetched again from
>   database again and kept into cache.

Please find the below sample ehcache configuration for spring.

```
<cache name="myProjectCache" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600">
</cache>
```

Also, refer the below spring cache documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

You can find a simple spring-ehcache example below:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Is there a way to do this without ehcache? I'd like to avoid adding a library for a single, simple caching method if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to use any caching framework, then you need to write a simple Java scheduler to update the cached data objects periodically (based on your requirements every 1 hour or 2 hours, etc..).